# JavaScript. Поросячья латынь

Tags: javascript

Решил написать код для "Поросячьей латыни". Суть игры:

- Если введённое слово начинается с гласной буквы, то прибавлять к введённому слову "вау";
- Если введённое слово начинается с согласной буквы, то перемещать первую букву этого слова в конец и прибавлять "ау";
- Если же слово начинается с "ь", "ъ" или с цифры, то не менять это слово.

Чтобы перебирать введённые слова, использовал `for`, внутрь которого поместил ещё два `for`, чтобы сравнивать первую букву введённого слова с массивами гласных и согласных букв:

```js
var sogl = "бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ";
var glasn = "аеёиоуыэюя";
var dr = "ъь";
var result = "";
var words = prompt();
var arr = words.split(" ");

for (var pM = 0; pM < arr.length; pM++) {
process();
function process() {
  for (var s = 0; s < sogl.length; s++) {
    if (arr[pM][0] === sogl[s]) {
        result = [result, arr[pM].slice(1) + arr[pM][0] + "ау"].join(" ");
    };
  };
    
  for (var s = 0; s < glasn.length; s++) {
    if (arr[pM][0] === glasn[s]) {
        result = [result, arr[pM] + "вау"].join(" ");
    };
  };
    
   if (arr[pM][0] !== sogl[s] && arr[pM][0] !== glasn[s]) {
        result = [result,  arr[pM]].join(" ");
    };
};
};
alert(result);
```

Всё работает, как нужно, но из-за последней конструкции `if`, правильно введённые слова записываются сначала в измененном виде, а затем ещё раз в оригинальном виде. А неправильно введённые слова записываются один раз. Как это исправить?

*Буду очень признателен за объяснение :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так происходит из за того что у вас перед последним `if` переменная `s` всегда равна 10. Так как вы ее объявляете в цикле выше и в этой строчке `for (var s = 0; s < glasn.length; s++)` она становится равна 10. Соответственно если слово будет начинаться не на букву `н` то будет выполняться это условие: `if (arr[pM][0] !== sogl[s] && arr[pM][0] !== glasn[s])`.

Исправить это можно так:
Вам вообще не надо последний `if`. Так как после того как вы определили на какую именно букву начинается слово и выполнения логики со словом можете сразу вернуть результат, остановив дальнейшее ненужное выполнение функции.

```js
var sogl = "бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ";
var glasn = "аеёиоуыэюя";
var dr = "ъь";
var result = "";
var words = prompt();
var arr = words.split(" ");

for (var pM = 0; pM < arr.length; pM++) {
process();
function process() {
  for (var s = 0; s < sogl.length; s++) {
    if (arr[pM][0] === sogl[s]) {
        return result = [result, arr[pM].slice(1) + arr[pM][0] + "ау"].join(" ");
    };
  };
    
  for (var s = 0; s < glasn.length; s++) {
    if (arr[pM][0] === glasn[s]) {
        return result = [result, arr[pM] + "вау"].join(" ");
    };
  };
  return result = [result,  arr[pM]].join(" ");
};
};
alert(result);
```